# How do I check required fields using 'empty' in a field whose value is an integer?

Tags: php, validation, radio-button

I'm trying to run a check of my required fields where i use the `empty` function. Unfortunately `empty` considers 0 to be empty and my values could be 0 and one in the radio button. I've tried to use `!is_int(myvalue)` and yet it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php   $required_fields = array('menu_name', 'position', 'visible');
    foreach($required_fields as $fieldname) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && !is_int($_POST[$fieldname]))) {
            $errors[] = $fieldname;
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you consider an empty value?

Comment: `$_POST` values are always strings if they're set, try just checking it against an empty string. `!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != ''`

Comment: Yes! This works. I've seen the code I posted work in a tutorial I watch but it just didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using empty and isset at the same time? Use `isset()` to check if the variable is defined. If it is, use `is_numeric()` to make sure it's numeric.

Comment: Thank you. It's a from a video tutorial I'm watching that the `is_int` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to test a string to see if it is an integer.

Try using is_numeric

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname])  // not in the post
   || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && 0 != $_POST[$fieldname]) // empty but not zero
   || (int) $_POST[$fieldname] == '')) // not an integer
) {
  $errors[] = $fieldname;
}
```